# How to combine two integers into one to save memory space?

Tags: integer, compression

I want to store two integer value into one memory location.

For example, x and y are two integers both of 4 digits (i.e. values ranges from 0 ~ 9999). I want to combine them to a single integer of 16 bit and decode them when needed (separate x and y).

Any idea or suggestion?

Comment: you need to post some code or tell us what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 1):

You can't.  There are 100,000,000 possible values for two integers in 0..9999.  There are only 65,536 possible values for a 16-bit integer.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot bitpack given X and Y into 16 bits. A single value in 0-9999 will consume 14 bits. That leaves only 2 bits for the second value.

You will need at least 28 bits.